# Suppose $u,v,w$ are nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $u \cdot v = u \cdot w = v \cdot w$. Prove that $A=\{u,v,w \}$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $u,v,w$ are nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with property that
$u \cdot v = u \cdot w = v \cdot w$.
Prove that $A=\lbrace u,v,w \rbrace$ is linearly independent.

My attempt so far:

$u \cdot v = u \cdot w \Leftrightarrow u(v - w) = 0$.
Since $u \neq 0$, then we must have $(v - w) = 0 \Leftrightarrow v=w$.
Analog, hence we have $u=v=w$.
So, for scalar $k_1,k_2,k_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $k_1+k_2+k_3=0$.
But it's linearly dependent.

Any idea ?

Comment: Your conclusion that $u\cdot (v-w)=0 \implies v-w=0$ is incorrect. For example $(1,0)\cdot (0,1)=0$, but neither argument is 0.

Comment: So............?

Comment: Why I can't? Since $u,v,w \neq 0$.

Comment: Well, see the counterexample in my comment above. It's true that for real numbers $a\cdot b=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$, but that's a completely different operation than the dot product. Recall the definition of the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^3: (x_1,x_2,x_3)\cdot (y_1,y_2,y_3)=(x_1y_1,x_2y_2,x_3y_3)$

Comment: Then..........?

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: is the problem was false?

Comment: Then....... try a different approach? Your very first step is wrong

Comment: is your definition of dot product above is true?

Comment: @arnold I think he got confused when writing the definition of the scalar product. It should be $x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3$.

Comment: oh okay great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fact that $x\cdot y=0$ you can only conclude that $x$ and $y$ are *orthogonal*. Certainly not that $x=0$ or $y=0$.

The obvious example is $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the standard inner product). Neither is zero, but their inner product is zero.

Let's try and use the assumptions. Call $p$ the common inner product and suppose $au+bv+cw=0$. Then we also have
$$
au\cdot u+bv\cdot u+cw\cdot u=0
$$
hence $a|u|^2+bp+cp=0$. Similarly, $ap+b|v|^2+cp=0$ and $ap+bp+c|w|^2=0$.

*If* $p=0$, you can conclude that $a=b=c=0$.

In general, the condition that $u,v,w$ are linearly independent is equivalent to
$$
2p^3-(|u|^2+|v|^2+|w|^2)p^2+|u|^2|v|^2|w|^2\ne0
$$
because this is the determinant of the linear system
$$
\begin{cases}
a|u|^2+bp+cp=0\\[4px]
ap+b|v|^2+cp=0\\[4px]
ap+bp+c|w|^2=0
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore the condition $u\cdot v=v\cdot w=w\cdot u$ is ***not*** sufficient to claim linear independence. An obvious counterexample is taking $u=v=w\ne0$.

It is interesting to note that the equation $2p^3-(|u|^2+|v|^2+|w|^2)p^2+|u|^2|v|^2|w|^2=0$ always has a negative and two positive solutions, except in the case when $|u|=|v|=|w|$, when the positive solution is double.

Comment: And so, they are linearly independent?

Comment: if $p=0$, then $a=b=c=0$ since $u,v,w$ are nonzero vectors, right?

Comment: @arnold Yes, right. Of course the assumption they're not zero is necessary, if we want to prove linear independence.

Comment: what if $u=v=w$? so they aren't linearly independent?

Comment: @arnold In that case $p=|u|^2\ne0$, of course. You can observe that in this case the polynomial becomes $2p^3-3|u|^2p^2+|u|^6$, which is zero for $p=|u|^2$. So you see that the assumption $u\cdot v=v\cdot w=w\cdot u$ is not sufficient for deriving linear independence.

Comment: @arnold I added a final note to my answer.

Comment: great, but are they still linearly independent without the property?

Comment: but if $p \neq 0$, are they still linearly independent?

Comment: @arnold What do you mean? Three equal vectors *cannot* be linearly independent.

Comment: of course. i mean that from your attempt above, if $p=0$, they linearly independent. But i ask when $p\neq 0$, are they still linearly independent?

Comment: @arnold If $u=v=w$, then $p=|u|^2\ne0$. And, in this case, $|u|^2$ *is* a root of the mentioned polynomial. Which is not a surprise, is it?

Comment: ah... i see. therefore, they are linearly independent if they aren't same, right? as $p=0$, then $a=b=c=0$ which it's linearly independent.

Comment: @arnold NO. They might be linearly dependent also when they're distinct, depending on the value of $p$. With $p=0$ you *do* get linear independence.

Comment: oh okay got it. thanks

Comment: @egreg Your computation boils down to determine the Gram-determinant of the vectors.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes, that's right, but under a special condition.